how to force block ram instead of LUT in VHDL?
xc7s25csga225-1 FPGA
Vivado v2023.2.2 (64-bit)
VHDL
i keep getting the error:
[DRC UTLZ-1] Resource utilization: F7 Muxes over-utilized in Top Level Design (This design requires more F7 Muxes cells than are available in the target device. This design requires 40806 of such cell types but only 7300 compatible sites are available in the target device. Please analyze your synthesis results and constraints to ensure the design is mapped to Xilinx primitives as expected. If so, please consider targeting a larger device.)
i think it is because synthesis is using LUT instead of RAM to implement some ROM in my design.
Synthesis report tells me:
ROM: Preliminary Mapping Report
+------------+------------+---------------+----------------+
|Module Name | RTL Object | Depth x Width | Implemented As | 
+------------+------------+---------------+----------------+
|cart        | ram        | 4096x8        | LUT            | 
|screen      | palette[0] | 128x24        | LUT            | 
+------------+------------+---------------+----------------+

the utilization report tells me:

Memory


+----------------+------+-------+------------+-----------+-------+
|    Site Type   | Used | Fixed | Prohibited | Available | Util% |
+----------------+------+-------+------------+-----------+-------+
| Block RAM Tile |    0 |     0 |          0 |        45 |  0.00 |
|   RAMB36/FIFO* |    0 |     0 |          0 |        45 |  0.00 |
|   RAMB18       |    0 |     0 |          0 |        90 |  0.00 |
+----------------+------+-------+------------+-----------+-------+

my VHDL for "cart" looks like:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity cart is
   port (addr      : in  std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
         en        : in  std_logic;
         clk       : in  std_logic;
         data_out  : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
         data_float: out std_logic);
end cart;

architecture behav of cart is
   type t_ram is array (0 to 4095) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
   signal ram : t_ram := (
      x"85",x"2b",x"a5",x"84",x"30",x"00",x"29",x"0f",
-- [510 lines similar to this removed for brevity]
      x"00",x"00",x"98",x"fe",x"98",x"fe",x"98",x"fe"
   );
   attribute ram_style : string;
   attribute ram_style of ram : signal is "block";

   signal tmp : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin

   data_float <= not en;
   data_out <= tmp;

   process(clk,addr)
   begin
      tmp <= ram(to_integer(unsigned(addr)));
   end process;

end behav;


but it is still implemented as LUT.
How do i force synthesis to use the RAM blocks on the FPGA instead of LUTs ???
i've tried all kinds of different approaches, like using a case statement, with and without clk.  nothing seems to work.  i tried using "IP Catalog" but i couldn't figure out how to make that work at all.  i tried adding "-ram_style block" and "-rom_style block".  i've been spinning on this for over a week and i'm very frustrated.

For a start, maybe you want to actually clock your ram process. See the user guide, Page 113 for inferring ram. Currently you have no clock, so a ram will not be inferred.

Block RAM requires at least one clock of pipeline delay. Since you have no delay, it's forced to use LUT RAM even though you applied the ram_style attribute.
Are you missing an if rising_edge(clk) there?
Check the Vivado docs for an example of inferred block RAM coding style.
